# Grunt / Gulp source files destination usage

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp

I am planning to use grunt/gulp to concat/uglify/obfuscate my hybrid app.

Source code:

```
js- 
  a.js
  b.js

css-
  a.css
  b.css
```

Now, my `index.html` loads the the above JavaScript and CSS files.

I concat and obfuscate the above `a.js` and `b.js` to file called `c.js`.
Its good practise to perform all tasks and have all those in single file i.e. `c.js` but my question is my `index.html` still points to `a.js` and `b.js`.

What happens to `c.js`? Is it never imported anywhere? We can simply uglify `a.js` and `b.js` itself and keep it as is.

And if so, how to use `c.js`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not planning to have grunt/gulp watch scripts, or just find it faster to develop with the non-minified files, and want to just run a task at the end to do all the production minification, then you can have a look at **processhtml**:

- grunt-processhtml: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml
- gulp-processhtml: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-processhtml

This plugin let's you include some markup in your HTML, which references the minified file, while including normal `<script>` tags for your unminified files.

```
<!-- build:js c.js -->
    <script src="a.js"></script> 
    <script src="b.js"></script> 
<!-- /build -->
```

So while you're developing, you can use `a.js` & `b.js`, and then once the `processhtml` task runs, it will strip them and use `c.js` instead. Of course it still relies on you doing the minification and concatenation to `c.js` yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

1. i think you should make separate folder for deployment purpose, let say you have folder `build` where your grunt/gulp result should be destined to, so the index.html always reference to the minified resources on the build `folder`,
2. may be this can help http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Comment: If so, a.js and b.js will still reside in project bundle , right ? In this case, do I need to manually delete a.js and b.js and link index.html to build/c.js ?

Comment: yes, for development purpose the a/b.js still the on the project folder, do not delete them, just put the build folder to the deployment e.g. your web server

Comment: @bowpunys Thanks :-) I got some good understanding on the process :)

Answer (score 1):

1: You build `a.js` and `b.js` into `c.js`, therefore just link to `c.js` in index.html.

2: There are many gulp/grunt plugins which supports minification

Grunt contrib-htmlmin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-htmlmin

Gulp gulp-htmlmin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlmin